# Else loop in java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

So I'm making a java program that will ask the user "how are you" and if the criteria in the if and if else statements isn't met then it should loop but i'm not sure how to implement the loop to make it so when the user doesn't input anything that is in both of the if statements it should repeat the code

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class simplechatbot {

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What is your name");
        String greeting = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Hi" + " " + greeting + ", ");

        System.out.print("How are you");
        String howareyou = scanner.nextLine();

        if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good")) {
            System.out.print("Thats good to hear!");
        } else if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("not good")) {
            System.out.print("Unfortunate");
        } else {
             /*
                this is where I want to put the loop that goes back to asking the user
                "how are you" until they say something which matches the criteria
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about `do-while` and make your condition to be repeated if what user wrote wasn't *"good"* and *"not good"*, be sure to `trim()` the response from user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while true loop forever unless one of the break conditions is met:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleChatBot {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("What is your name");
                String greeting = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Hi" + " " + greeting + ", ");

                System.out.print("How are you");
                String howareyou = scanner.nextLine();
                if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good")) {
                    System.out.print("Thats good to hear!");
                    break;
                } else if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("not good")) {
                    System.out.print("Unfortunate");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop which you only break from when your desired conditions are met, repeatedly prompting the user to type a desired value:

```
while(true) {
    if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good");
       System.out.print("Thats good to hear!");
       break;
    } else if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("not good"){
        System.out.print("Unfortunate");
        break;
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter a valid response:");
    howareyou = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in a `while` loop and then use the `break` statement to break out of the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class simplechatbot{

    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("What is your name");
        String greeting = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Hi" + " " + greeting + ", ");
        while(true){
            System.out.print("How are you");
            String howareyou = scanner.nextLine();
            if(howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good");
               System.out.print("Thats good to hear!");
               break; // jumps to "here"
            }else if(howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("not good"){
               System.out.print("Unfortunate");
               break; // jumps to "here"
            }
        } 
        // <- "here"; continue with the rest of your program at this line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `do while` loop should work nicely for this use case. Something like this:

```
String howareyou = null;
do {
    System.out.print("How are you");
    howareyou = scanner.nextLine();
while (!howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good") && !howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("not good"));

if (howareyou.equalsIgnoreCase("good");
    System.out.print("Thats good to hear!");
} else {
     System.out.print("Unfortunate");
}
```